# Wordpress template file for custom post type category (type) and tag pages?

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, jetpack

I'm working with the Jetpack Portfolio module.

I have a custom archive (archive-jetpack-portfolio.php) which works great when going to mysite.com/portfolio.

But, when I go to mysite.com/project-type/thisthing or mysite.com/project-tag/thatthing it is still loading the standard template archive (archive.php).

How do I either get WP to use archive-jetpack-portfolio.php for project-type (basically categories in JetPack) and project-tag pages (the optimal situation I believe) or to add custom template pages for these?

Have tried the following:

- category-jetpack-portfolio.php
- category-jetpack-portfolio-thatthing.php
- category-thatthing.php
- taxonomy-jetpack-portfolio.php
- taxonomy-jetpack-portfolio-branding.php
- taxonomy-branding.php

None of those seem to work.

Have googled all over the answer, but nothing.

Comment: Instead of creating seperate archive file you can simply use conditional tag as per post type and tags, insert your post query under that condition and all will work fine..

Comment: Also this Codex page may solve your issue: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/has_tag/

Comment: @JohnySantiago

Do you mean something like this in archive.php?

            if ( is_post_type_archive( 'jetpack-portfolio' ) ) {
              get_template_part( 'content', 'jetpack-portfolio-archive' );
            } elseif ( is_tax('jetpack-portfolio-type') ) {
              get_template_part( 'content', 'jetpack-portfolio-archive-type' );
            } elseif ( is_tax('jetpack-portfolio-tag') ) {
              get_template_part( 'content', 'jetpack-portfolio-archive-tag' );
            } else {
              get_template_part( 'content', 'archive' );